# Matplotlib Xtick Overlap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I need to add spacing between each tick so that it does not overlap. The current code to calculate the x ticks is

```
x = np.arange(-10, 361, 10, dtype = int)
plt.xticks(x)
```

But the plot it produces is 
[image]

I also tried adding space using the following code:

```
x = np.arange(-10, 361, 10, dtype = int)
plt.xticks(x,['%i   '%w for w in x])
```

But this only adds spacing around the first label(-10) and nothing after that.
I don't want to reduce the font size and was hoping for another alternative to avoid the overlap.

Comment: Well, what sort of "other alternative" are you looking for? As I see it, you have three main options: 1) increase the size of the figure, 2) reduce the size of the tick labels, 3) reduce the number of ticks. Personally I would go with number 3. I suppose that a fourth option would be to rotate the labels, but that is usually more helpful when the labels themselves are long strings. If none of those options suit you then you're probably asking for the impossible.

Comment: I see. Hmm how about increasing the size of the figure? I will be storing the plots as images. The reason for having so many ticks is that one look at the plot and you can get pretty accurate angle and power without looking at the data file itself.

Comment: If that's your goal then do you really need to label all of the ticks? How about just having tickmarks and/or gridlines for the minor ticks?

Comment: I see.. Yea the sounds like a good idea. Since I am just a beginner I am not sure how to go about doing that. Let me look at how to do that and get back to you. Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to only label every *n<sup>th</sup>* tickmark. You can do this by using a combination of major and minor ticks:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10, 361, 10, dtype = int)
y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(2*x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticks(x, minor=True)        # set minor ticks for each x value
ax.grid(which='both', axis='both')  # show grid lines

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Update:

**@tcaswell** rightly pointed out in the comments that using one of the [tick locator classes](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) would be cleaner than directly setting the positions of the ticks. For example:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(10))
```

[image]

Note that this will automatically place tickmarks that span the whole x-axis, regardless of how you pan or scale the axes of the plot.

Comment: Is it necessary to create a subplot and figure. I tried to do it directly plt.xticks(x, minor=True) but it says that minor is not a valid property

Comment: Alright I got it to work by using plt.minorticks_on() and changing the range of x to x = np.arange(0, 361, 50, dtype = int).... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `plt.minorticks_on()` will work in this case, but it doesn't offer any way to change the locations of the minor ticks if you don't like the default. Another option would be to use use `plt.gca()` to grab the current axis object, e.g. `plt.gca().set_xticks(...)`. Personally I would recommend using the object-oriented interface rather than trying to do everything with '`plt.`' function calls - it offers much more control and also makes your code more readable.

Comment: That makes sense could you point out some reading material I can use regarding oops for matplotlib?

Comment: You might find [this tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html#artist-tutorial) helpful. I mainly tend to explore the different attributes and methods of objects within an IPython session. For example, if you have an axis object called "`ax`" you can type "`ax.`" at the prompt and hit <Tab>, and you will see a list of its public methods and attributes. If you want to know what a particular method does, you can type "`help(ax.set_xticks)`" (or in IPython, just "`ax.xticks?`") and hit <Enter> to view the docstring for that method.

Comment: I would avoid using `set_xticks` directly.  It is much better to use the locator classes.

Comment: @tcaswell `set_xticks` since it seemed closest to the OP's original code, but you're right that using a Locator would be cleaner.